# WatchKit: Video Duration

Tags: objective-c, swift, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos

Is there a way to determine the duration of a video currently set to `WKInterfaceInlineMovie`? I need to implement a circular progress bar displaying a current progress.

I have a URL of the file initially downloaded from network. It plays well, but I haven't found any way to determine its length (actually, nor questions asking that which is strange).

Of course, I can ask the backend server to send this info, but I'd like to avoid such complications if possible.

Comment: AFAIK no. Just curious - from where do you want to get the playback progress? Timer once you call `playFromBeginning`? There's no duration available nor the playback progress.

Comment: @zrzka Perhaps, something like this. Depends on what answers are received, I was hoping that there are more opportunities in WatchKit than I'm aware of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, it seems I overcame the WKInterfaceInlineMovie API limitation by the help of AVFoundation and CoreMedia.

I create `AVAsset` object using a movie URL from a shared folder (`AVAsset(url:)`). Then I get `CMTime` duration from the `AVAsset`'s `duration` property (which is a `CMTime` object).

Actually, I was very surprised to find out that it works. I'm still testing it, because it's too good to be true and I'm expecting to run across some pitfalls. I'll update the answer if anything else's found.